# Using Uploadify to POST Directly to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, uploadify

Can anyone tell me how to use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) to upload directly to Amazon S3?

My code is as follows:

```
$('#fileInput').uploadify({
  'fileDataName' : 'file',
  'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
  'script'    : 'http://BUCKET-NAME-GOES-HERE.s3.amazonaws.com/',
  'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
  'method'    : 'post',
  'auto'      : true,
  'onError': function (a, b, c, d) {
    alert('error '+d.type+": "+d.info + ' name: ' + c.name + ' size: ' + c.size);
  },
  'scriptData' : {
    'AWSAccessKeyId': "KEY-GOES-HERE",
    'key': "${filename}",
    'acl': "public-read",
    'policy': "POLICY-STRING-GOES-HERE",
    'signature': "SIGNATURE-GOES-HERE",
    'success_action_status': '200'
  }
});
```

My (unencoded) policy string looks like this:

```
{
  "expiration": "2100-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"bucket": "BUCKET-NAME-GOES-HERE"},
    {"success_action_status" : 200},
    ["starts-with", "$filename", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$folder", ""],
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 1, 209715200]
  ]
}
```

Using the above code actually allows me to select a file, which it then appears to upload (somewhere), but nothing shows up in my S3 bucket and no errors are returned to the JS console.

Using a regular HTML form to post a file to the S3 bucket works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [thread](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/1416/uploading-to-amazon-s3/p1) the uploadify forum:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uploadify.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#fileInput').uploadify({
         'fileDataName' : 'file',
          'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
          'script'    : 'http://UPLOADBUCKET/',
          'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
          'auto'      : true,
          'onError' : function(errorObj, q, f, err) { console.log(err); },

          'scriptData' : {
              AWSAccessKeyId: "ACCESS_KEY",
             key: "foo/${filename}",
             acl: "public-read",
             policy: "POLICY STRING"
             signature: "SIGNATURE,
                success_action_status: '200'
             }

          });
    });
// ]]></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The base for the policy string is as follows:

```
{ "expiration": "2100-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
"conditions": [
  {"acl": "public-read" },
  {"bucket": "UPLOADBUCKET" },
  {"success_action_status" : '200'},
    ["starts-with", "$filename", "" ],
    ["starts-with", "$folder", "" ],
    ["starts-with", "$key", "foo"],
    ["content-length-range", 1, 209715200]
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would be better to include an explanation of the solution, even just a quick recap.

Comment: Dead link :(  You should copy pasta the solution into SO in the future

Comment: @sohaan it's the S3 signature.. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a direct upload to Amazon S3 with progress bar working ive got a working demo here.

If anyone is interested it will support buckets and folders within bucket working on producing a wordpress plugin for this.

This is using swfupload, tho working on uploadify ill post when its done.

http://www.isimpledesign.co.uk/blog/amazon-s3-direct-multiple-file-upload-progress-bar

Comment: Did you ever get this to work with Uploadify? I can only get it to work intermittently

Answer (score 0):

this is the java code for saving image into s3cloud.
add this code into your uploadscript file (like uploadify.php) you will have your own uploadify script file.

AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials(_ACCESS_KEY,
                _SECRET_KEY);

```
    log.info("oovfilepath : " + oovfilepath);
    log.info("name : " + name);
    S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(credentials);
    S3Bucket s3Bucket = s3Service.createBucket(_BUCKET_NAME);
    AccessControlList bucketAcl = s3Service.getBucketAcl(s3Bucket);
    bucketAcl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.ALL_USERS,
            Permission.PERMISSION_READ);

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(oovfilepath);

    S3Object s3Object = new S3Object(s3Bucket, name);
    log.info("s3Object:" + s3Object);

    s3Object.setAcl(bucketAcl);
    s3Object.setDataInputStream(input);

    log.info("s3Object:" + s3Object);

    s3Service.putObject(s3Bucket, s3Object);
```