# Uploading Multiple Files to S3 using JQuery

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, http-post

I have been trying to upload multiple files to S3 in a sequential way. i.e . 
2 files A and B

Upload file A (no redirection on Success) then upload file B (bigger file) and redirection upon success.

```
function StartPosting(data) {   
var s3JsonList = JSON.parse(data.s3Json);   
PopupSpinner();    
 $.each(s3JsonList, function (k, v) {    
  HttpPostToS3(k, v);
});
```

}

```
 function HttpPostToS3(key, value) {   
document.getElementById(key + 'S3SubmitDiv').innerHTML = value;//This sets the Post variables in the order.   Also key + 'S3SubmitDiv'   
setTimeout(function () {   
  jQuery('#' + key + 'form').submit();   
}, 3000);
```

}

Basically there are 2 forms where each form is meant for the respective file.
What happens is , if i put a debugger both the files are uploaded to S3 in debug mode. but when i disable the debugger only the 2nd file is uploaded to S3.

My questions are
1-What is the best way to upload to S3 using jQuery/HttpPost
2-Is there any way to get confirmation in the same form itself that the file has been uploaded?
3-Also get a progress bar while uploading.

Any suggestions will be of great help to me .

Thanks .

**EDIT**

I just made a tweak to get the above code to work

When i applied Set timeout function to both the files apparently only second one was being uploaded.
For the first file i did not apply any wait. for the second file i applied a wait for 5 secs.

```
 function StartPosting(data) {
var i = 0;
var s3JsonList = JSON.parse(data.s3Json);
PopupSpinner();
$.each(s3JsonList, function (k, v) {

  if (i == 0) {
    HttpPostToS3(k, v);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(function () {
      HttpPostToS3(k, v);
    }, 5000);
  }
  i++;
});
```

}

Yes the code is ugly!! but it just works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

These articles will provide you enough information:

[Using Uploadify to POST Directly to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682825/using-uploadify-to-post-directly-to-amazon-s3)

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/03/upload-to-amazon-s3-with-uploadify/

http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/4713/amazon-s3-and-uploadify-sample/p1