# Passing a file upload to a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

I have the following architecture:

`Web-Application <-> Web-Service <-> Cloud`

The web-application provides a html page for uploading a file which should be placed in the cloud. It is, by design, not possible to upload directly to the cloud (this is really no option here).

What I could do is, to upload it to the web-application and save the file to disk, then upload it to the web-service, save to disk and finally upload it to the cloud. But because the file could be large (4GB+) it would be nice just to pass the stream from the web-application to the web-service and the web-service passes it to the cloud, so it does not get saved to file anywhere instead of the cloud.

Is this possible with C#, .NET 4, ASP.NET and MVC 4?

Comment: The answer depends on which cloud service are you using. For S3, i'd check out Uploadify which has support for this scenario. Check out this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682825/using-uploadify-to-post-directly-to-amazon-s3]

Comment: Follow up. Just looked through my old references and came across this: [http://codeonaboat.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/uploading-a-file-to-amazon-s3-using-an-asp-net-mvc-application-directly-from-the-users-browser]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really easy.

Within my Web-Application Action I just created a new HttpWebRequest, copied the file's inputstream to the HttpWebRequest and sent it to the Web-Service. Same thing from Web-Service to the Cloud. So no storage to disk is needed.